# How to convert a String into a Float

Tags: objective-c, string, decimal

From my `textfield` I get a `string` like `25,50`.

I want to convert this `string` into a `float`. But if I use `myFloat = [mytextfiel.text floatValue];` I just get `25.00`.

Is there a method to get a float like `25.50`?

Comment: why not input a dot instead of a comma (as floats are usually interpreted) ?.

Comment: @giorashc not in Europe , is the decimal point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace the comma with a dot when you extract the float

```
myFloat = [[mytextfiel.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."] floatValue];
```

Comment: Disclaimer - WRONG ANSWER. It won't parse correctly numbers like @"1.000,2"

Answer (score 5):

Replacing the commna with a period works, but you can also use an `NSNumberFormatter` and set your locale appropriately (note: untested code):

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
formatter.localizesFormat = YES;
float myFloat = [[formatter numberFromString:string] floatValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `NSLocale` to determine what to do and accomplish it with NSScanner in case you have no access to `NSNumberFormatter`:

1. Wash off number groupers, like `1.000.000,00` -> 1000000,00
2. Scan off non-numeric leading characters.
3. Scan out the integral part of the number as a string.
4. Scan off non-numeric character between the integral and fraction parts.
5. Scan out the fraction part as a string.
6. Reassemble a string with format `@"%@.%@"`.
7. Parse that reconstructed string.

This will parse out virtually any case of use, i.e. 1.500,50€ in German, 1,500€50 in French, $1500.50 in English will all result in number `1500.5`

Answer (score 0):

Floats must follow the decimal point format (no matter which region of the world), it means that the final product of your string must have a . instead of the comma. I suggest you replace it before storing in a database or before processing the value.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
float floatNo = [[@"25.50" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."] floatValue];
NSLog(@"%f",floatNo);
```

**O/P**

```
25.500000
```